# Html Table design. Which is better:A large number of rows in a single table or large number of table with few rows each

Tags: html, css, web, page-load-time

I need to design a web page which consists of a large number of fields each one to be dispalyed in a row of table..  There are several categories.  I wish to make a separate table for each category and design it differently.

Does the presence of a large number of tables on a web page makes it slower?
Which is better.. have 10 tables with 10 rows each or a single table with 100 rows?  IS there any significant difference with respect to speed of page loading?

Answer (score 0):

Doing something like that, I would recommend using one table, but heavily using your thead and tbody elements to contain each individual section.

Edit:  I did a bit of testing, and found no significant increase using one or teh other.  On my machine, I wound up with about 1800ms (averaged using 10 tests for each subject) page generation time for a single table with 10000 rows and 5 columns, as well as 10 tables with 1000 rows and 5 columns each.

Code used for testing:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var start_time = (new Date()).getTime();

            function detectTimeDiff(){
                alert("Time taken:  "+((new Date()).getTime() - start_time)+" milliseconds.");
            } 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="detectTimeDiff()">
        <?php
            $multiple_tables = true;
            $table_count = 10;

        ?>
        <table>
        <?php
            $table_count--;

            for($i=0;$i<10000;$i++){
                if($multiple_tables){
                    if($i%$table_count == 0){
        ?>
        </table>
        <table>
        <?php
                    }
                }

        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any reason specific to page load statistics of performane issue or it's just a conventional practice.

Comment: Practice, mainly.  But I would bet you would see a small (though likely not noticable) increase in page load time.